# Laravel 5.8 reset password link not working. I am able to send mail with reset password link, but when I click it, It says "Object not found"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am using deafult laravel reset password. No custom route added. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this? I check my route list. I hide the  email and password for security reason. I also checked the database that the email is exist or not.

**My .env file:**

```
    APP_NAME=CMS
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:6LAFCVCiznjI2d1MkvDZdEYebrm2XMi02tB5wWxxFZ4=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://localhost

    LOG_CHANNEL=stack

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=cms
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=

    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_LIFETIME=120

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
    MAIL_PORT=465
    MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx@gmail.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    AWS_BUCKET=

    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
    PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

    MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
    MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

**Error I got:**

[image: Thats the error I got when I clicked reset password link.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `php artisan serve` on your local machine, change your `APP_URL` to reflect your local development environment:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

**NOTE:** When you make changes in your `.env` file you need to restart your  server in order to see the effects. If `php artisan serve` is running in your terminal, terminate it (CTRL + C  on windows), and restart the `php artisan serve` command.

Comment: I tried this....that didn't work for me. I restart the server and clear the cache also.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue on your URL.

Its trying to access your laravel app on `http://localhost/password...`

for this to work properly you have to add correct url on your .env file

Example: 
If you are using `php artisan serve`
Then you have to set

`APP_URL=http://localhost:8000`

And if you aren't using php artisan then you need to set it

`APP_URL=http://localhost/<project_name>/public`

Comment: are you using php artisan ? try `php artisan config:clear` or restart the `php artisan serve`

Comment: I am not using artisan.

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` run this command and refresh the page then